# Rails: Installing Twitter-Bootstrap 3 in a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am a total n00b and am trying to install Twitter-Bootstrap 3 into my rails project. The twitter-bootstrap-rails gem is unfortunately only for version 2.0, otherwise I would totally use that. Is there some kind of set up magic I need to do in my app to configure it with my Rails project other than copy and paste the Bootstrap directories into my rails project repo?

Any and all advice much appreciated!

Comment: Check out this answer to a previous question in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15868449/1512956 or, if you don't mind losing the LESS/Sass magic, just copy over the CSS and JS files to vendor as you said.