# Rails/Bootstrap 3: Trouble Manually Setting Up Bootstrap 3 in Rails 3

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap-3, dependencies, stylesheet

I am followed the directions on the workflow from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868229/rails-app-using-a-gem-vs-including-source-with-twitter-bootstrap/15868449#15868449), but I am getting the following error:

```
Undefined variable: "$zindex-navbar".
(in /Users/thalatta/code/aviary-hours/app/assets/stylesheets/_navbar.scss)
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/_navbar.scss:13
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in    `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2018644895263320512_70131537402780'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:25:in `block in <class:ApplicationController>'
```

Now the variable `$zindex-navbar` is most definitely in my `_variables.scss` partial. Here is it in the file:

```
$zindex-navbar:            1000 !default;
```

which is in my `app/assets/stylesheets` dierectory and is `@imported` by my `bootstrap.scss` file 
in the following line:

```
@import "variables";
```

which, `bootstrap` itself is imported by my `application.css.scss` file here:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Now my concern is that it is not loading all of my dependencies properly and I am not sure how that happened.

`application.css.scss`

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
@import "bootstrap";
```

Is the problem that the `application.css.scss` is of `.scss` extension and therefore is not called in the stack trace from `application.html.erb`? How can I properly set up my assets to load the built in dependencies that twitter-bootstrap has (i.e. all of the `@import <partialname>` lines in the bootstrap code)

Thank you so much for your help.

Ever yours,

Micha'el.

Comment: please let me know if you would like to see any part of my repo / any of my files!

Comment: also it is a mystery why  `_navbar.css.scss` is called immediately after `application.html.erb` in lieu of `application.css.scss`. Perhaps this might be a clue?