# What is a best way to customize Bootstrap3 in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Twitter Bootstrap 3 has been released recently. We're going to use in a new project and customize it to fit our needs.

Here're a few issues we came across in the past 2 projects.

- as TB is written with LESS it will took some time unless there is a reliable SASS version
- working with unstable SASS version we found out that styles were imported more than once - this is perhaps due to the old SASS bug that includes the same files more than once
- we could't make 'include-once' workaround work with SASS version from the gem
- we figured out that the best what we can do is build TB from the builder but…
- it requires a lot of work on our part just to do simple modifications like e.g customizing navbar as we can't just override the default variables

We are looking for a solution that would make customizing Bootstrap less problematic. What is your experience? What strategy do you use? Have you tried to use TB3 in Rails(4)?

Comment: Did you have any problems with this? https://github.com/jlong/sass-bootstrap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your options is to use [**jlong's sass implementation**](https://github.com/jlong/sass-bootstrap). Follow these steps for setting up Bootstrap3 to work with Rails 4 (this is my way of doing it, also look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868229/rails-app-using-a-gem-vs-including-source-with-twitter-bootstrap/15868449#15868449) and also checkout this **[project](https://github.com/hugodias/railStrap)** as well.)

Step 1: Download the **[zip](https://github.com/jlong/sass-bootstrap/archive/master.zip)** from jlongs repo.

Step 2: unzip the file and copy all the contents of the lib folder.

Step 3: Go to your rails4 `vendor/assets/stylesheets` folder and make a folder and call it `bootstrap`. Now paste to this `bootstrap` folder what you copied a second ago. So your folder will look like this:

[image]

Also copy the `fonts` folder from the extracted zip file you downloaded from the repo and add it to your `vendor/assets/stylesheets` folder:

[image]

Step 4: Go to your `app/assets/stylesheets` folder and make a file and call it whatever, for example `main.scss` and add the following to it:

```
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss";
```

Step 5: Start overriding bootstrap using this file. For example:

```
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss";
$grid-columns:              16;
$grid-gutter-width:         2px;
.left{
    @include make-lg-column(8);
}
.right{
    @include make-lg-column(8);
}

section{
    @include make-row();
}
```

**Sample HTML file:** (for example about.html.erb)

```
<div class="container">
  <sction>
    <div class="left">
      <div class="well">
        <h1>hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="well">
        <h1>hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

**Results**

[image]

Step 6 (optional): Happy railstrapping !

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely better way than overriding vanilla CSS!