# how do I open bootstrap gem in sublime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

I'm building a project and I need to override the default styles of bootstrap in the source code . So how do I access the source code ?

Comment: It's better not to use a gem for Bootstrap if you want to override styles. Check out this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15868449/1512956

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the location of your gem files with `gem env`.

mine is

INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0

then the .less files are in `/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.2.8/vendor/toolkit/twitter`

I don't know what you want to do, but there are many variables for customizing bootstrap without changing any of the source, see - http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html#variables

Answer (score 0):

just fork the gem in github, clone it to your local, modify it, then push it, after that if you want to use it in your rails project, just add your forked git source in your Gemfile like this:

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", git: "https://github.com/xxxx/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git"
```